# The best way to check if a variable is a function in javascript

Tags: javascript

Which is a best way to check if a variable is a function?

```
var cb = function () {
  return;
}

if (!!(cb && cb.constructor && cb.apply)) {
  cb.apply(somevar, [err, res]);
}
//VS
if (!!(cb && 'function' === typeof cb) {
  cb.apply(somevar, [err, res]);
}
```

Comment: As easy as `if(typeof cb == 'function') { ... }`

Answer (score 10):

The most common way would be to use:

```
(typeof foo === 'function')
```

But if you want to match function-like objects (which are uncommon, but can be useful), you can check whether the object is invokable:

```
(foo && foo.call && foo.apply)
```

In most cases, you can also test the constructor (very similar to `typeof`):

```
(foo.constructor === Function)
```

If you want to provoke an exception, you can always:

```
try {
  foo();
} catch (e) {
  // TypeError: foo is not a function
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd say the second one since it's the simplest, most intuitive and works .